# Unity3d Linerenderer not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw a line between two UI GameObjects with Linerenderer. In scene mode everything work fine, but in game mode line is invisible. I tried to change Z position of objects but lines are still invisible. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

```
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private float counter;
private float dist;
private Vector3 aPos;
private Vector3 bPos;
public Transform origin;
public Transform destination;
public float lineDrawSpeed = 6f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    aPos = new Vector3(origin.position.x, origin.position.y, origin.position.z); // Using these to move the lines back
    bPos = new Vector3(destination.position.x, destination.position.y, destination.position.z);

    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, aPos);
    lineRenderer.SetWidth(3f, 3f);

    dist = Vector3.Distance(origin.position, destination.position);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (counter < dist)
    {
        counter += .1f / lineDrawSpeed;

        float x = Mathf.Lerp(0, dist, counter);

        Vector3 pointA = aPos;
        Vector3 pointB = bPos;

        Vector3 pointAloneLine = x * Vector3.Normalize(pointB - pointA) + pointA;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, pointAloneLine);
    }

}
```

Comment: dumb question, but what color is your background? I once made a lineRenderer the same color and I thought it was invisible also.

Comment: My background is something like green and lines are white

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking some logic error in the code you've posted, I think the problem might be with the material.

**Generic debugging help for line renderers:**

Try setting the color/material of the line renderer:

```
lineRenderer.sortingOrder = 1;
lineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Sprites/Default"));
lineRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps you need to specify the number of vertexes manually?

```
mineLaser.SetVertexCount (2);
```

Finally, if these both don't work, it might just be a logic error; try setting the transforms for the `lineRenderer`'s position to be some predefined value and see if it shows up.

**For this specific question:**

Ah, so its on a canvas. Assuming you mean the UI canvas, I believe linerenderer is the wrong tool to use in this situation. Check out [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1201050/is-there-way-to-have-line-renderer-on-a-canvas.htmlhttp://).

One of the answers there suggests to:

> just use a panel filled with any color you want and use Height and Width to set the length and the Width of your line

Comment: I tried this but, unfortunately, lines still not showing in game mode. May it be because I am trying to draw line on Canvas?

Comment: @AlexRED canvas indeed may be the problem. Updated answer.

Comment: I just had OP's bug all of a sudden and setting the sortingOrder to 1 solved it, but why tho?

Comment: @Nicekor I believe the default value for sortingOrder is 0. If its never set, everything, including your line renderer is drawn at order 0. By putting the renderer at 1, you explicitly tell Unity to draw it above those other elements (behind which it could have been hidden)

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible in "Screen Space - Overlay" Canvas mode. In that mode UI overlay draws on top of everything in Scene (including LineRenderer, that actually non UI element).

Try to use "Screen Space - Camera" option for your Canvas and "Use World Space" option for you Line Renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have forgotten to set sorting layer for the line renderer. As this could only be the possible reason if the line is visible in the scene view and not in the game view.